# How to extract a bunch of data from JSON matching an array of ids

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

In Javascript, I have a dataset (JSON) of posts. Each post has a `post_id`. I have an array of `post_id`s that I would like to use to extract certain posts from the main dataset.

```
const dataset = [
     {post_id: 1, title: 'First Post'},
     {post_id: 2, title: 'Second Post'},
     {post_id: 3, title: 'Third Post'},
];
```

and then i have the array with *which* posts i want to get:

`const posts_to_get = [0,3];`

How would I parse the dataset to extract where `id = 0` and `id = 3`?

My array might contain many many ids, so i'd need to iterate over it i guess. Thinking there's a bunch of loops i could do but it doesn't feel right.

*Note*: I'm doing a 'mock backend' for a frontend application at the moment. Longer-term I'd of course do a lot better/more efficient fetching of posts. But at the moment I've got this one JSON dataset to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: Are `post_id`s unique?

Comment: @AndyGaskell yep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const dataset = [
     {post_id: 1, title: 'First Post'},
     {post_id: 2, title: 'Second Post'},
     {post_id: 3, title: 'Third Post'},
];
const posts_to_get = [1,3];
var result = dataset.filter(p=>posts_to_get.includes(p.post_id))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. I don't think this works though? When I test it, it only returns the last post. i've not heard of `includes` before though

Comment: Actually that does work! I had 0,3 as the ids, but 1,3 of course does work!

Comment: This works inside snippet, changed `posts_to_get` to print 2 of 3 posts. `includes` is kinda new, look here: [moz docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) . If you're targeting older browsers, you might use for example `.indexOf(p.post_id) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large dataset it's probably worth it to convert the array to an object before trying to read.

```
const m = dataset.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    obj[cur.post_id] = cur;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Look ups will be constant time (though you will have to convert the post_id you're looking for to a string:

```
const ids_to_find = [1, 3];
console.log(ids_to_find.map(i => m[i.toString()]));
```